# Algorithms - Both Little o and Big Omega on the same functions?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity, little-o

I have two functions, `f(n),g(n)` such that `f(n)=o(g(n))`.

**to be clear, I'm taking about little o**

It is possible with that information given to me, that `f(n)=Omega(g(n))`.

To me it sounds that it's not possible, since Little-o definition says to me that

```
for every c>0,f(n)<c * g(n).
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that both f and g are strictly positive.

f(n) = o(g(n)) means f(n)/g(n) -> 0 as n tends to infinity.

f(n) = Ω(g(n)) means [(assuming the Knuth definition of Ω)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) g(n) = O(f(n)), which means there's a c>0 such that for large enough n, g(n) <= cf(n). But then, for large enough n, f(n)/g(n) >= 1/c > 0. So it's not possible that f(n)/g(n) -> 0 as n tends to infinity, which means that it's impossible that f(n) = Ω(g(n)) and f(n) = o(g(n)).

Answer (score -1):

No this does not guarantee that. Sometimes, big O is the same as Omega(g(n)) but not all the time.

Comment: Thanks, However I was talking about little o

Comment: Oops. I believe you're right. But your equation is just off a little bit, the < should be <=. For every c>0,f(n)<c * g(n), it should be for every c>0,f(n)<=c * g(n).